# PROLOG Sum of a list created from facts

Tags: list, prolog

I want to create a list from the facts. And the list should contains only one of the arity in the facts.

For example :

```
%facts
abc(a, b, c).
abc(d, e, f).
abc(g, h, i).
```

Sample :

```
?-lists(A).
  A = [a, d, g];
  No.
```

EDIT :

Using the suggestion by `Vaughn Cato` in the comment, the code become this :

```
%facts
abc(a, b, c).
abc(d, e, f).
abc(g, h, i).

lists(A) :-
    findall(findall(X, abc(X, _, _), A).
```

The list is created, but how to sum up the list `A` ?

If sum of list for input from query,

```
sumlist([], 0).
sumlist([X|Y], Sum) :-
    sumlist(Y, Sum1),
    Sum is X + Sum1.
```

But if want to sum the existing list, how to define the predicate?

Comment: How about findall(X,abc(X, _ , _ ),A).?

Comment: How about `?- lists(A), sumlist(A, Sum)`? Of course you can also use the builtin predicate proposed by @sharky.

Comment: @AlexanderSerebrenik, it's work with that. I had write this as a rule too, and it's work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Vaughn Cato, it's help me a lot by using `findall(X,abc(X, _ , _ ),A).` to create the list I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

To sum a list of numbers such as that produced by your definition of `lists/1`, most Prolog systems (e.g., [GNU](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc218), [SWI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sum_list/2)) implement `sum_list/2` which takes a list of numbers as the first argument and binds their sum in the second:

```
?- sum_list([1,2,3],Sum).
Sum = 6.
```

Comment: Is the `sum_list/2` is a predefined predicate? I'm currently using the WIN-Prolog, and I tested using your example, seems like it's not defined.

Comment: Whoops! You're right, no library implementation of `sum_list/2` in WIN-Prolog. The definition you've added to the question seems fine, though.

Comment: ps. If you're new to Prolog and have your choice of implementations, I highly recommend [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/). It's free, runs on Windows, and has lots of useful library functions.

Comment: But my lecturer requested to use `WIN-Prolog`, and we are given the `WIN-Prolog` with license too. Anyway, thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve it with aggregate_all/3. It eliminates need to build list in memory if you just need a sum.

```
sum_facts(Template, Arg, Sum) :-
   aggregate_all(sum(X), (call(Template), arg(Arg, Template, X)), Sum).
```

In this example I use a generic call with defined Template:

```
sum_facts(abc(_, _, _), 1, Sum).
```

If you will always use it with the first arg of abc/3 this version will be enough:

```
sum_facts(Template, Arg, Sum) :-
   aggregate_all(sum(X), abc(X, _, _), Sum).
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm very new in Prolog. It'll take time for me to understand your rules. Build the `list` in memory can help me in the future, I think. Anyway, I'll appreciate your answer.